# Accessing individual bits in MIPS

Tags: algorithm, assembly, mips, bit, maze

I'm writing a program in MIPS that solves a maze using a left-hand rule algorithm. I already have my algorithm written, but I need to find a way to keep track of the spaces in the maze that I've already visited so that I can find the "best" and most direct solution to solve the maze.

In the program, register $t9 is a 32 bit number that stores information about the location of the car that traverses the maze, including column and row position, which is what I need to isolate. Basically, all I need to know is how to work with/isolate those specific bits.

Bits 31-24 is an 8-bit number representing the row in 2's compliment
Bits 23-16 is an 8-bit number representing the column in 2's compliment

tl;dr I just need to extract the first 8-bits, and the next 8-bits from a 32 bit number located in $t9 in MIPS

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get bits 31-24, perform a logical shift right (`SRL`) by 24. The remaining number will correspond to the value of those bits, as interpreted as an 8-bit integer.

To get bits 23-16, shift right by 16, then AND by 0xff.

Will you figure out the MIPS commands for that?

Comment: You don't need to mask 8 bits of 32bit value shifted right by 24 bits - when logical shift right was used, as those upper 24bits were filled with zero anyway.